# Google IAP In App Purchase auto-renewing subscriptions Webhook for Subscription update / cancellation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, google-iap

Is there any way to implement a Webhook for automatic update of subscriptions on server side, in nodejs for example, for situations such as: the user renewed or canceled his subscription?

Currently I save the subscription data in my Database after purchase and use the [Google Developers API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) to verify that it has been renewed or canceled when necessary.

However, for some Administrator routines I need to check all subscriptions at once and this includes calling the Google API for each one. This process is slow and can take a long time.

I could create a method that checks and updates all subscriptions according to the Google API response, and leave this process running through a Cronjob every day at night. I believe it will work, but a server-side Webhook would be the ideal solution.

Something which **automatically notifies my server as soon as there is a change to a subscription** so that I can update it in my DB immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. We can use Google Cloud Platform (GCP) to subscribe to topics and receive real-time notifications when a subscription change.

All steps are described in detail in their documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn